# How to pass a parameter to Toaster's onClick event?

Tags: javascript, toastr

I'm in the following scenario: I've to open a page at Toastr notification click.
Consider the popup is shown in the real scenario when a notification arrives from SignalR. In the dojo I've created it's simpler since I've got an object called test

You can reach the dojo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jx1f4grL/1781/)

The code is the following:

```
$(function () {

var test ={"Message" : "ciao"};

toastr.options.onclick = function(e) {alert(test.Message); }

$('#error').click(function () {
    // make it not dissappear
    toastr.error("Noooo oo oo ooooo!!!", "Title", {
        "timeOut": "0",
        "extendedTImeout": "0"
    });
});
$('#info').click(function () {
    // title is optional
    toastr.info("Info Message", "Title");
});
$('#warning').click(function () {
    toastr.warning("Warning");
});
$('#success').click(function () {
    toastr.success("YYEESSSSSSS");
});
```

});

I wish to pass the test object as a parameter, not as a global one

Comment: from where the parameter will be pass ? you want `$('#success').click` to send parameters on the `toastr.options.onclick` ?

Comment: I want to pass as the user clicks on the notification popup a parameter,in this demo it's ok to pass it from the click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it's not too late - but on similar case this helps to me:

```
    toastr.options.onclick = function(e) {alert(this.data.Message); }

        $('#error').click(function () {
            // make it not dissappear
            toastr.error("Noooo oo oo ooooo!!!", "Title", {
                "timeOut": "0",
                "extendedTImeout": "0", 
                "data": {"Message": "ciao error"}
            });
        });
        $('#info').click(function () {
            // title is optional
            toastr.info("Info Message", "Title", {
                   "data": {"Message": "ciao info"}
            });
        });
        $('#warning').click(function () {
            toastr.warning("Warning");
        });
        $('#success').click(function () {
            toastr.success("YYEESSSSSSS");
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pyob98fj/

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciated